# The document exists on MongoDB, but the result of ``show collections'' is empty

Tags: mongodb

I inserted some data (document) into my MongoDB. But the result of ``show collections'' is empty.

How to fix this issue, and what's happened with my DB?

PS. I am using MongoDB V3.2.0, but it works fine in V3.0.7

*Add new collection and data:*

```
> db.createCollection("test")
{ "ok" : 1 }
> db.test.insert({time:Date()})
WriteResult({ "nInserted" : 1 })
> db.test.find()
{ "_id" : ObjectId("56e76424b6beadc42a9eced9"), "time" : "Tue Mar 15 2016 01:23:48 GMT+0000 (UTC)" }
```

*Empty results:*

```
> show tables
> show collections
> db.getCollectionNames()
[ ]
```

Comment: Are you using a user account for authentication to access? If so then you do not necessarily have permission to list collections. Probably a good thing. See [listCollections](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/privilege-actions/#authr.listCollections)

Comment: No, I am not. I just create a new MongoDB sever (V3.2.0) by default configures.

Comment: Show us how you are connecting to the mongodb shell. This does look exactly like when an account lacks the necessary role.

Comment: mongo --host 127.0.0.1 --port 27018

Comment: btw, it works fine in V3.0.7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can You please check the version Of the Shell.There is a known issue where list Collections return an empty list when old version of the shell  is been used. Use db.version() to check your shell version

Comment: MongoDB shell version: 2.4.9

Comment: You are right. The default mongo shell apt is too old of my MongoDB server.